# Host not found trying to restrict access to yahoo.com in elinks using squid

Tags: squid, elinks

I added this in squid.conf

```
acl blocked_sites dstdomains .yahoo.com
http_access deny blocked_sites
```

and this in elinks.conf

```
set protocol.http.proxy.host = "proxy.localhost:3128"
set protocol.http.proxy.passwd = ""
set protocol.http.proxy.user = ""
```

And i get HOST NOT FOUND

Comment: Please, again, do not cross-post your question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/229359/why-do-i-get-host-not-found-when-using-a-restricted-squid-proxy-in-elinks

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that you can't resolve `proxy.localhost:3128`. You should probably change it to `localhost:3128` in your elinks.conf